# Monte Carlo Method in Python

Tags: python, montecarlo

I've been attempting to use Python to create a script that lets me generate large numbers of points for use in the Monte Carlo method to calculate an estimate to Pi. The script I have so far is this:

```
import math
import random
random.seed()

n = 10000

for i in range(n):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    z = (x,y)

    if x**2+y**2 <= 1:
        print z
    else:
        del z
```

So far, I am able to generate all of the points I need, but what I would like to get is the number of points that are produced when running the script for use in a later calculation. I'm not looking for incredibly precise results, just a good enough estimate. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you wish to count how many random pairs are inside the circle? If that's the case just use a counter...

Answer (score 15):

If you're doing any kind of heavy duty numerical calculation, considering learning `numpy`. Your problem is essentially a one-linear with a numpy setup:

```
import numpy as np

N   = 10000
pts = np.random.random((N,2))

# Select the points according to your condition
idx = (pts**2).sum(axis=1)  < 1.0
print pts[idx], idx.sum()
```

Giving:

```
[[ 0.61255615  0.44319463]
 [ 0.48214768  0.69960483]
 [ 0.04735956  0.18509277]
 ..., 
 [ 0.37543094  0.2858077 ]
 [ 0.43304577  0.45903071]
 [ 0.30838206  0.45977162]], 7854
```

The last number is count of the number of events that counted, i.e. the count of the points whose radius is less than one.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can run `enumerate` on `range` and get the position in your iteration:

```
In [1]: for index, i in enumerate(xrange(10, 15)):
   ...:     print index + 1, i
   ...:
   ...:
1 10
2 11
3 12
4 13
5 14
```

In this case, `index + 1` would represent the current point being created (`index` itself would be the total number of points created at the beginning of a given iteration). Also, if you are using Python 2.x, `xrange` is generally better for these sorts of iterations as it does not load the entire list into memory but rather accesses it on an as-needed basis.

Comment: @ahans No problem - I remember seeing it for the first time and thinking 'Ah, figured there was a way to do that.' Have fun using it!

Answer (score 1):

Just add *hits* variable before the loop, initialize it to 0 and inside your if statement increment *hits* by one. 
 
Finally you can calculate PI value using *hits* and *n*.

```
import math
import random
random.seed()

n = 10000
hits = 0  # initialize hits with 0

for i in range(n):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    z = (x,y)

    if x**2+y**2 <= 1:
        hits += 1
    else:
        del z

# use hits and n to compute PI
```